# Why can I use the new version of go's API even though I specified the old go version in go.mod?

Tags: go

I specified `go 1.15` in go.mod and then used the new API of go 1.16 in my code and it works fine.

my `go.mod`:

```golang
module go_test

go 1.15
```

my `a.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
)

func main() {
    os.CreateTemp("", "*.txt") // os.CreateTemp was introduced in go 1.16
}
```

my local golang version is 1.16 and it works fine:

```sh
go version
// go version go1.16 darwin/amd64
go run a.go // no errors
```

---

What confuses me is that if I use the `embed` library (also a new feature introduced in go 1.16), I get an error when compiling:

```
go:embed requires go1.16 or later (-lang was set to go1.15; check go.mod)
```

---

There is a similar question in this issue but I didn't find a clear answer:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43980#issuecomment-770306226

Comment: `embed` is a language feature. Library functions are not.

Comment: I seem to understand that if I just `import _"embed"` it also doesn't report an error. The error is this comment `// go:embed`. It's because of the request in this commit https://github.com/golang/go/commit/0575e35e506cb180c5743209684b57dd41b4365f.

Comment: Proper use of anything with embed need 1.16 and thats all there is to know.